# C# Remove inventory

Tags: c#

Hello sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to coding (using C#) so that's why, I'm doing this inventory atm and I'm trying to figure out how to delete inventory after choosing that option, its only one string and not using lists. 
Am I mission something? prob am but I'm lost atm

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var meny = true;
            var item = new List<string>();
            string inventory = "Nothing stored";
            while (meny)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" \tWelcome to the inventory");

                Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Add item");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Show your inventory");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Delete your inventory");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");
                Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                // switch 
                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nAdd item: ");
                        inventory =(Console.ReadLine());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine(inventory);

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tRemoving items ");

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        meny = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nError, Not a valid value, Try again");
                        break;
```

EDIT:
First of all thank u all for being so fast and really helpfull. i really appriciate it alot! :D In this case or project that is supose to only store 1 item in inventory and delete that item in case 3 i found by a comment here that i only needed to use inventory = null; for the project to work like its suppose to. I also completely removed the line var items = new List(); cuz its not needed when im not using a list atm :D

But again thank u all! :D

Comment: You don't seem to be using this line: `var item = new List<string>();`

Comment: If `inventory`, not `item`, is the "inventory" in question, then it seems like you just need `inventory = "Nothing stored";`, `inventory = "";`, or `inventory = null;` in `case 3`.

Comment: under case 3 right? if u put it under case 3 i get this error:

Error - CS0136 A local or parameter named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

Comment: "item" is your list.  It should be "items" by the way, since it's a list.  You add things to that list.  `inventory =(Console.ReadLine());` is just assigning the user input to that variable, but your code doesn't add that item to your list.

Comment: BACON: tho it helped with inventory = null; didnt think it was just that easy to just give inventory the value of 0 to delete the items in inventory. 
This way does not work then using ``` new List<string>();```

Comment: The question says "its only one string and not using lists", which I read as meaning that you're not looking to use the `item` list right now.  Is `inventory` the inventory, or `item` is the inventory and `inventory` is the human-friendly description?  As @LarsTech points out your code is not interacting with `item` in any way after creating it, and I thought the focus of this question was to keep it that way.

Comment: Im not gonna use a list, only i added "item" atm, i will use lists later on in my progress. so i realized after you pointed it out that ``` var items = new List<string>(); ``` is not in use in this code. so i removed that line.

Comment: I see.  So it sounds like setting `inventory` to a `null`/empty/default string is what you were looking for?

Comment: `Add` doesn't add, it replaces.

Comment: In general, try to choose a data type that fits the data. If you're storing multiple items, use a collection, like an array or a list, not a string. It will make adding, removing, counting, items etc. much easier.

Comment: @KrilleKarlsson, hey Krillie, It would be nice if you consider accepting one of the solutions below by clicking the green tickbox. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the inline comments first, however, you weren't adding any items to your list. You do this by using the `.Add` method.

Then when you want to delete an item in your inventory, you need to check what index you want to delete in that list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;    
...


public static List<string> inventory = new List<string>();
public static void printInventory()
{
    Console.WriteLine("===Your Inventory===");
    foreach(var item in Enumerable.Range(0,inventory.Count)) // Loop through inventory to get all the items.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item+": "+inventory[item]);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var meny = true;

    while (meny)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" \tWelcome to the inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Add item");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Show your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Delete your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");
        Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

        int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        // switch 
        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("\nAdd item: ");
                inventory.Add(Console.ReadLine()); //Add items to your inventory
                break;
            case 2:
                printInventory(); // Print all the items in your inventory
                break;
            case 3:
                printInventory(); // Print all the items in your inventory
                Console.WriteLine("\nSelect what Item you want to delete");
                // If you want to delete the entire inventory...
                // just use inventory.Clear(); here instead of what's below.
                try
                {
                    int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Take input selection
                    inventory.RemoveAt(entry); // Remove selected entry in inventory
                } 
                catch(FormatException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input, please use numbers.", ex);
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                meny = false;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nError, Not a valid value, Try again");
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the inline comments.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var meny = true;
    var items = new List<string>();
    string newInventoryItem = "";
    while (meny)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" \tWelcome to the inventory");

        Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Add item");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Show your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Delete your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");
        Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

        int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        // switch 
        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("\nAdd item: ");

                // Read the new item from the console
                newInventoryItem = Console.ReadLine();

                // Add it to our list of inventory items.
                items.Add(newInventoryItem);

                break;
            case 2:

                //take our items, and put together a string
                // where each item is on a new line
                var itemStr = string.Join("\r\n", items);

                Console.WriteLine(itemStr);

                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tRemoving items ");

                // Remove everything from the list
                items.Clear();
                break;

            case 4:
                meny = false;
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nError, Not a valid value, Try again");
                break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var meny = true;
    var items = File.ReadLines("inventory.txt").ToList();

    while (meny)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" \tWelcome to the inventory");

        Console.WriteLine("\t[1] Add item");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Show your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Delete your inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Quit");
        Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

        int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        // switch 
        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("\nAdd item: ");
                items.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            case 2:
                if (items.Length > 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", items));
                else Console.WriteLine("Nothing in inventory");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tRemoving items ");
                items.Clear();
                break;
            case 4:
                meny = false;
                File.WriteAllLines("inventory.txt", items);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nError, Not a valid value, Try again");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show how to interact with the `item` list to store an inventory, but since, for the purposes of this question, the goal was to [use `inventory` to store the inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012390/c-sharp-remove-inventory/60012600#comment106135058_60012390), you can do that by simply setting the variable to `null`...

```cs
case 3:
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tRemoving items ");
    inventory = null;
    break;
```

...or an [empty `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.empty) like this...

```cs
inventory = string.Empty;
```

...or this...

```cs
inventory = "";
```

...or the `string` with which it was initialized...

```cs
inventory = "Nothing stored";
```

For any of those options a [constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const)...

```cs
const string EmptyInventory = "Nothing stored";
```

...or [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) field...

```cs
readonly string EmptyInventory = string.Empty;
```

... would be more maintainable...

```cs
case 3:
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tRemoving items ");
    inventory = EmptyInventory;
    break;
```

Comment: @Joel Yes, that would revert `inventory` back to whatever value represents an empty inventory, defined in either of the prior two code snippets.